# Looking to delete empty space (working with HTML)

Tags: html, css

I am a complete newb with coding, and I'm running into a bit of trouble with some text on my website. The code I am using is as follows:

```
<p><div style="font-family:blog_script"><font size="7">Hi, We're <b>The Distance</b><p></p></font></p>
</a> 
</div><p>
```

I would really appreciate any help with:

1. The spacing in between each line (I would like for the lines to be slightly further apart)
2. There is also a lot of empty space below the text creating a large gap between the HTML code and the normal text on the site, I would like to get rid of this.

See our website for a [demo link](http://www.thedistancelive.com/).

I'd really appreciate any tips you can give me.

Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="font-family: blog_script; line-height: 1;">
  <font size="7">Hi there, We're 

    <b>The Distance</b>
  </font>
</div>
```

I have set `line-height` for the div. Try this. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the associated style sheet for this. For a quick fix for problem 1, you can try putting new line between the lines -

> Blockquote

"Hi, We're **The < br> Distance**"

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

See you could use `line-height` for reduce spacing. Like one I found on you site. Similarly as below you have to target parent element with different `class` and `id` and set his line-height accordingly.

```
#siteWrapper {
    font-family: "Kameron",Georgia,serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em; /*Line height reduce this and adjust*/
    letter-spacing: .4px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Check this simple example which helps you to understand how `line-height` and letter-`spacing works` [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/038sdzbz/1/)

Comment: Thank you for this :) Do you know how to get rid of the empty space below the html box please? x

Comment: Welcome @SophieJones that can be reduce by adjusting height value or if you have assigned any padding reduce there values.

Comment: @font-face {
  font-family: blog_script;
  src: local("blog_script"),
       local("blog_script"),
       url(http://carlisle-houses.co.uk/classes/d/instashow/font.php);
  font-weight: bold;
}
.blog_sript
{
  font-family:blog_script;
}
.correction{
    line-height: 1em;
    word-spacing: 0.0em;
} << this is all i can see in the CSS x

Comment: @SophieJones for example this codes reduce your hi there we are distance div height and aligns the line-height too. Same search in your css file for line-height, height, letter-spacing reduce there values and save and check. <div class="index-section-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1469761817519_4621" style="height:500px; line-height:20px; letter-spacing:1px">

Comment: @SophieJones Welcome :-) do up-vote or accept the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom css class to manage any adjustments you need to do to a certain HTML element.

```
.more-height {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Add the class name to the class="... property of the "we are the distance"  like this:

```
<div style="font-family: blog_script;" class="more-height">
```

This will make the distance between the lines a bit higher.

You can also inject the style of the div element above with the "line-height" property like this:

```
<div style="font-family: blog_script; line-height: 1;">
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Could i quickly ask - if i wants less height what would i write please?

Comment: define that by pixles until you get the right height needed.

Comment: lign-height: 10px; as an example. Increase or decrease until you get the right height.